# invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What is this kind of problem in installing mysql in WSL?

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                                                                              [ OK ]
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Function not implemented
                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-serverE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am running it in ubuntu 18.04 version, attempted to uninstall/reinstall but still got the same error.

Sometime success but did not ask for password which preventing me to connect using heidesql

Answer (score 2):

To determine current runlevel, you can use `RUNLEVEL` variable.

If you want to disable reconfiguration of services during install, use the following syntax:

```
RUNLEVEL=1 sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

To reconfigure the package manually, run:

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```